# generate random numbers with no zero

Tags: java

How do I get random number in the range st 1 to 45 only (not included zero). Here is my code so far:

```
int number;

Random randomNum = new Random();

number = randomNum.nextInt(45)+1;

for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++) {

        number= randomNum.nextInt(45);

        if (i==6) {
            System.out.printf("%d",number);
        }
        else {
            System.out.printf("%d-",number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Come on... generate 0-44 and add 1?

Comment: You've done `number= randomNum.nextInt(45)+1;` **once**, do it ***twice***.

Comment: ah. i see now the problem

Answer (score 2):

`randomNum.nextInt(45) + 1` will generate a number from 0 to 44 and add 1, thus generating numbers from 1 to 45.